# GPU Filters on UnsafeMutableRawPointer in iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, swift3

I am actually working with image processing on iOS10 with iPad Pro.
I have written small Swift3 image processing app to test the speed of image processing.
My decoder sends every ~33ms (about 30 FPS) new frame, which I need to process with some CoreImage filters of iOS without additional buffering. Every ~33ms the following function will be called:

```
func newFrame(_ player: MediaPlayer!, buffer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer!,
              size: Int32, format_fourcc: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!,
              width: Int32, height: Int32, bytes_per_row: Int32,
              pts: Int, will_show: Int32) -> Int32 {

    if String(cString: format_fourcc) == "BGRA" && will_show == 1 {
        // START
        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
        let ret = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault,
                                               Int(width),
                                               Int(height),
                                               kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                               buffer,
                                               Int(bytes_per_row),
                                               { (releaseContext:
                                                  UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
                                                  baseAddr:
                                                  UnsafeRawPointer?) -> () in
                                                // Do not need to be used
                                                // since created CVPixelBuffer
                                                // will be destroyed 
                                                // in scope of this function
                                                // automatically
                                               },
                                               buffer,
                                               nil,
                                               &pixelBuffer)
        // END_1

        if ret != kCVReturnSuccess {
            NSLog("New Frame: Can't create the buffer")
            return -1
        }

        if let pBuff = pixelBuffer {
            let img = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pBuff)
                      .applyingFilter("CIColorInvert", withInputParameters: [:])
        }
        // END_2
    }
    return 0
}
```

**I need to solve one of the following problems:**

- Copying **CIImage img** raw memory data back to **UnsafeMutableRawPointer buffer** memory.
- Somehow apply GPU image filter to **CVPixelBuffer pixelBuffer** or **UnsafeMutableRawPointer buffer** directly

The code bloc between *// START* and *// END_2* need to be run in less than 5ms.

**What I know:**

- The code between *// START* and *// END_1* runs in less than 1.3ms.

Please help with your ideas.

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found temporary solution:

1) Create CIContext in your view :

```
imgContext = CIContext(eaglContext: eaglContext!)
```

2) Use a context to draw filtered CIImage to the pointer's memory:

```
    imgContext.render(img,
                      toBitmap: buffer,
                      rowBytes: Int(bytes_per_row),
                      bounds: CGRect(x: 0,
                                     y: 0,
                                     width: Int(width),
                                     height: Int(height)),
                      format: kCIFormatBGRA8,
                      colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())
```

This solution works well as it uses SIMD instructions of iPad CPU. But the CPU utilization only for copy operation is too high ~30%. This 30% will be added to CPU usage of your program.

Probably somebody has any better idea how let GPU directly write to UnsafeMutableRawPointer after CIFilter?